# How do I run a pipeline for Business Central in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, cicd

Our Business Central extension is located on GitLab, and I've been trying to get the CI/CD feature to work. What I'd like to do is to use BcContainerHelper to set up a BC container and run a Test Runner of my choice before letting the pipeline succeed. Unfortunately, I've found very little documentation on this subject, and what I've found was either about BC pipelines in Azure, or pipelines for other projects in GitLab.

When creating the docker container, is it possible to set it up with BcContainerHelper instead so I have BC set up right away? Also, I tried to execute a `.ps1` file, but I got the following error message:

```
Checking out fb0f1471 as 2-implementing-testapp...

Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:13fd310aa3adfd5db7b986cc64b5b6816bea774cf51de468d917e6ef038b418f for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:d273723056dda84bda81454eb42743c6c29fdf2c2d4d42bddf8e3dca8bb99aa4 ...
$ ./scripts/create-container.ps1
/bin/bash: line 120: ./scripts/create-container.ps1: Permission denied
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is it even possible to run a pipeline for Business Central on GitLab or do I have to use Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about GitLab (we use Auzre DevOps with ALOps in our organization) but I can provide my two cents about `BcContainerHelper`.

`BcContainerHelper` has a command that will run a full build pipeline (creates the container, compiles the app, runs the tests). It is called `Run-AlPipeline`.

An example of running it could be:

```
Run-AlPipeline `
    -pipelineName "My Pipeline" `
    -licenseFile "c:\temp\license.flf" `
    -baseFolder "...path to your project..." `
    -appFolders @("app") `
    -testFolders @("test") `
    -installTestFramework `
    -enablePerTenantExtensionCop `
    -enableUICop
```

You can read about all the parameters available in [this blog post](https://freddysblog.com/2020/10/08/run-alpipeline/).